# How to pass two arguments when one argument is `find "path/" -type f -name "*.xml"`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, sh

How to pass two arguments when one argument is `find "path/" -type f -name "*.xml"`?

```
$files=`find "path/" -type f -name "*.xml"`
python3 script.py  $files "path/result.xml"
```

In the above statement, it is taking only one argument and "path/result.xml" is including in the first argument.

Comment: Did you try `"$files"`?

Comment: Your question is not really about Python but about shell scrripting. And in the first line, `$files=...` is probably incorrect, unless the variable `files` has been already defined. Did you mean `files=...`?